# Accessing HW from browsers?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, safari

I saw [Accessing Hardware Devices](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_hardware.html), which looks great for Chrome.

What are the closest libraries for doing the same from IE and Safari? Firefox? Others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Internet Explorer, look into ActiveX. There are also browser helper objects (BHOs), and probably a few other mechanisms. IE doesn't really have anything like the same security model as Chrome, so hardware access is at the same time harder (because there's no explicit support in browser APIs) and easier (because you pretty much just do it).

For Firefox, good keywords to search on are "boot to gecko" and "firefox os." You'll find that Mozilla is working on all sorts of cool [device APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Reference?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Apps%2FReference).

No idea on Safari, sorry.